# File path error when creating model (String error)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

The following error message occurred.
"The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String’"

[[image]]

[image: img]

I don't understand why this is an error.
If there is anyone who knows the solution, please let me know.

i want to make model and solve that...
thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `imageFilePath` could be null so that means:

```dart
final face = Face(name:faceName,imagePath:imageFilePath!);
```

**or**

You could make the field imageFile in your Face class **null-aware**:

```dart
class Face {

final String name;
final String? imagePath;

Face({required this.name,required this.imagePath});

}
```

then you can easily do this:

`final face = Face(name:faceName,imagePath:imageFilePath);`

There is another option if you don't want to do the above two suggestions:

```dart
final face = Face(name:faceName,imagePath:imageFilePath ?? '');
```

Comment: @HHYK Please could tick my answer correct

Answer (score 0):

`imageFilePath` is  a nullabe String, you can  do null check and proceed the way did for `faceImagePath`.

```dart
if(imageFilePath!=null){
   ....
}
```